# Problems with ISSET since upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, isset

I'm having problems with the following bit of code which hasn't worked since I upgraded to php 5.5

```
//direct to login page if no login or no password in header
If (!isset($login_password) || ($login_password=="") || ($login_password=="0") || !isset($login_name) || ($login_name=="") || ($login_name=="0")) {
    $page = "login";
}
```

I've adapted it to the following but its still failing.

```
//direct to login page if no login or no password in header
If (!isset($_SESSION['$login_password']) || ($_SESSION['$login_password==""']) || ($_SESSION['$login_password=="0"']) || !isset($_SESSION['$login_name']) || ($_SESSION['$login_name==""']) || ($_SESSION['$login_name=="0"'])) {
    $page = "login";
}
```

The login uses the following

if ($login_click)
  if (isset($login_password) && ($login_password!="") && isset($login_name) && ($login_name!="")) {
    $login_password = md5($login_password);
    setcookie("login_name",$login_name);
    setcookie("login_password",$login_password);
    header("Location: game.php");
}

Any suggestions on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: What problems? You need to provide more detail.

Comment: Where do your variables come from? And putting php comparissons in array keys is probably not what you want. And you should not store passwords in sessions.

Comment: what you're doing in the adapted version of the code is very confusing.  the keys you're using to access values in $_SESSION would likely look more like `$_SESSION['login_password'] == ""`.  your code seems to be pretty unorganized and messy! checking for logged in status should be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

Try just simple `empty` function:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['login_password']) || empty($_SESSION['login_name']))  {
//...
```

Comment: empty is not deprecated!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. However you can greatly simplify it using `empty`

```
if (empty($login_password) || empty($login_name)) {
  $page = "login";
}
```

Most likely this isn't the problem, and your problem is elsewhere.